# How can you get 1 million bytes easily?

Tags: astroneer

We all know that bytes are important, lots of things cost lots of bytes, is there a way to get 1 million bytes easily?

Comment: Just curios, what do you need 1 million bytes for?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there are currently two ways of obtaining bytes:

- Doing research on Artifacts and plant Seeds. Look for the special pyramid boxes for the best artifacts.
- Completing tasks. Not all tasks yield bytes, but some do.

For research you can simply build lots of research stations and plant seeds. The plants will yield artifacts from time to time but also new seeds. Extra seeds can be used for research as well, so it turns literally into a 'Byte Farm'

Comment: You missed a big one IMOP, and that is harvesting the small mineral and organic deposits! On the harder planets these can yield nearly 1k bits each